# Firing Greasemonkey after xmlhttp post request

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I wrote the following Greasemonkey script to make the reading experience easier in the site http://www.pib.nic.in/newsite/erelease.aspx?relid=0.

The code works very much fine. But for only one issue. On selecting the drop down boxes on the left to view the old archives, I am unable to call the function contentreplace() which is happening through xmlhttp request. I tried to achieve it through anonymous functions at the end using a time delay. Since the loading time varies each time, the call for the function is not happening always.

It would be a great help to make the code perfect if there is a way to call the function contentreplace() after the xmlhttp post request.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Press Information Bureau Main
// @description     PIB Open links in new tab, Color change on click, make scrollable
// @include         http://pib.nic.in*
// @include         http://www.pib.nic.in*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @version         3
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/




if( window.location.toString() =='http://www.pib.nic.in/'  ) {
  //do nothing
}
else if( window.location.toString() =='http://www.pib.nic.in/newsite/mainpage.aspx'  )     {
  //do nothing
}

else if($.trim(window.location.toString())=='http://www.pib.nic.in/newsite/erelease.aspx?relid=0' ) {


contentreplace();
makescroll();
lichangecolor();
}
else {

deletenodes();
}


//------------ function contentreplace() ---------------//

//Function to replace the Getrelease to the url

function contentreplace(){

//-- Use jQuery selector to get just the <li>s that have an onclick.
var articleLinks    = $("#lreleaseID li[onclick]");

//-- jQuery .each()
articleLinks.each ( function () {
var jThis           = $(this);  // "this" is a special var inside .each()
var onClickVal      = jThis.attr ("onclick");
var articleMatch    = onClickVal.match (/Getrelease\s*\((\d+)\)/i);

if (articleMatch  &&  articleMatch.length == 2) {
    var articleId   = articleMatch[1];
    var articleUrl  = "http://www.pib.nic.in/newsite/erelease.aspx?relid="
                    + articleId
                    ;

    jThis.attr ("onclick", "window.open('" + articleUrl + "')");

}
} );
}

//------------- function makescroll() -------------------------------//

//Function to change the left side scorllable
function makescroll(){
$('.leftrightdiv').css('height','300px');
$('.leftrightdiv').css('overflow','scroll');
}


//--------------- function lichangecolor() ---------------------------------------//


//li item change color on click
function lichangecolor(){
$("li").click(function(){

$(this).css("color","red");
});
}


//-------------------- function deletenodes() --------------------------//
//Function to remove nodes
function deletenodes(){

//delete this for ministry delete
ministry=document.getElementById('minID').parentNode;
ministry.parentNode.removeChild(ministry);

//delete this for newslinks delete
newslins=document.getElementById('relhead').parentNode;
newslins.parentNode.removeChild(newslins);

//delete this for newslinks near by delete
    newslinksadj=document.getElementById('relhead').parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[9];
newslinksadj.parentNode.removeChild(newslinksadj);

}




//---------------- function $() -----------------------//

//Function for detecting drop down change
(function($) {
$.fn.selected = function(fn) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var clicknum = 0;
        $(this).click(function() {
            clicknum++;
            if (clicknum == 2) {
                clicknum = 0;
                fn(this);
            }
        });
    });
}
})(jQuery);


//------------ Anonymous functions () ---------//


//On change of Ministry

$('#minID').selected(function() {

setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    contentreplace();
    lichangecolor();
  }, 900);

});

//On change of Date Drop down
$('#rdateID').selected(function() {
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    contentreplace();
    lichangecolor();
  }, 900);

});

//On change of Month Drop down
$('#rmonthID').selected(function() {
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
contentreplace();
lichangecolor();
  }, 900);

});

//On change of year Drop down
$('#ryearID').selected(function() {
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    contentreplace();
    lichangecolor();
  }, 900);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

It difficult to find then modify the XMLHttpRequest instance from the page script.

But there are other way, listen the dom change then re-run your replace function. You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver).

Here is the code snippet to listen the archive list change

```
var contentreplace = function(mutation) {
    alert('changed');
};

var target = document.querySelector('#lreleaseID');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(contentreplace);
});
observer.observe(target, {childList: true});
```